# Django : No Reverse Match on password reset

Tags: django

I am working on password reset functionality in Django using custom templates.
But when I entered mail:id and clicking on reset password I'm facing "No Reverse match error".Please someone help me,I understand this is an old problem, I have followed other answers and tried solving but could not come up with solution.Please find the code below and help me solve this problem.

**urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset,password_reset_done,password_reset_confirm,password_reset_complete
from surveysite.views import home,about,login,loggedin,loggedout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$',about, name='about'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', login, name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$',loggedin, name='loggedin'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', loggedout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/password_reset/$', password_reset, 
        {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password_reset/mailed/'},
        name="password_reset"),
    url(r'^accounts/password_reset/mailed/$',password_reset_done),
    url(r'^accounts/password_reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13})-(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',password_reset_confirm, 
        {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password_reset/complete/'},name="password_reset_confirm"),
    url(r'^accounts/password_reset/complete/$',password_reset_complete),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Password_reset_email**

```
{% autoescape off %}
You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.get_username }}

Thanks for using our site!

The {{ site_name }} team

{% endautoescape %}
```

**Error Stack Trace**

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password_reset/

Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': 'MQ', u'token': u'4jz-530973903a3b600e2a97'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/password_reset/
Django Version:     1.10.5
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': 'MQ', u'token': u'4jz-530973903a3b600e2a97'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 392
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.13
Python Path:    

['G:\\Manoj\\Software Engineering-Yui Man lee\\Django_Project\\surveysite',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\Tools\\Scripts',
 'G:\\Manoj\\Software Engineering-Yui Man lee\\Django_Project\\surveysite',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']

In template G:\Manoj\Software Engineering-Yui Man lee\Django_Project\surveysite\templates\registration\password_reset_email.html, error at line 6
```

I have tried solutions from below links but could not find the solution.

- [NoReverseMatch on password_Reset_confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143393/noreversematch-on-password-reset-confirm)
- https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/issues/380
- [django password reset NoReverseMatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745674/django-password-reset-noreversematch-error)

I'm following tutorial from http://code.techandstartup.com/django/reset-password/ ==> customized Templates.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, It's working with Chrome browser but yesterday I'm working with Firefox and its not working,might be issue is with my browser settings.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of referencing the view, you need to just reference the name of your url pattern that you are trying to match

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}
```