# Exception Error on Password Reset loop for Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have created a login system with the ability to reset the password.

The request is working perfectly when I click on "Forgot Password?"I receive the reset link however when I click the link in the email I get the error message. "Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/reset_password_validate/MzM/brm129-52c795f84dc89b21234642b2166f5c4f/
Exception Value: reset_password() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uidb64'"
[image: image of error messatge appearing in browser]

I kept thinking the URL path was not routing but I have changed this twice and I am getting the same error message.
URL.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Other URL patterns...
    path('registerUser/', views.registerUser, name='registerUser'),
    path('registerBusiness/', views.registerBusiness, name='registerBusiness'),
    # Update the URL pattern to use the login view

    #path('accounts/login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('myAccount/', views.myAccount, name='myAccount'),
    path('custDash/', views.custDash, name='custDash'), 
    path('bussDash/', views.bussDash, name='bussDash'),  

    path ('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),

    path('forgot_password/', views.forgot_password, name='forgot_password'),
    path('reset_password/', views.reset_password, name='reset_password'),
    path('reset_password_validate/<str:uidb64>/<str:token>/', views.reset_password, name='reset_password_validate'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

from business.forms import BussForm
from .forms import UserForm
from .models import User, userProfile
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model, login as auth_login
from .utils import detectUser, send_verification_email
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator

from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

# Create your views here.

#restrict user access to wrong dashbaords
def check_role_buss(user):
    if user.role == 1:
        return True
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
    
def check_role_customer(user):
    if user.role == 2:
        return True
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied

# create user with form from website
def registerUser(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, 'You have already logged into your account')
        return redirect('dashboard')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            # user = form.save(commit=False)  # Create a User instance without saving to the database
            # user.set_password(password)
            # user.role = User.CUSTOMER  # Assign the role to the user
            # user.save()  # Save the user to the database

            #create user from create usert method
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            #phone_Number = form.cleaned_data['phone_Number']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name, username = username, email = email, password = password)
            user.role = User.CUSTOMER  # Assign the role to the user
            user.save()

            #send email verifcation
            send_verification_email(request, user)

            messages.success(request, 'Your accounts has been registered!')
            return redirect('registerUser')
        else:
            print('invalid entry')
            print(form.errors)
        
    else:
        form = UserForm()

    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'accounts/registerUser.html', context)

def registerBusiness(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, 'You have already logged into your account')
        return redirect('dashboard')
    elif request.method =='POST':
        #store data and creare the business
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        b_form = BussForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and b_form.is_valid:
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name, username = username, email = email, password = password)
            user.role = User.BUSINESS
            user.save()
            business = b_form.save(commit=False)
            business.user = user
            user_profile = userProfile.objects.get(user=user)
            business.user_profile = user_profile 
            business.save()

            #send verifcation email business 
            mail_subject = 'Please activate your account'
            email_template = 'accounts\emails\account_verif_email.html'
            send_verification_email(request,user, mail_subject, email_template)

            messages.success(request, 'Your business has been saved sucesfully and is now under approval')
            return redirect('registerBusiness')
        else: 
            print('invalid form')
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UserForm()
        b_form = BussForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'b_form': b_form,

    }
    return render (request, 'accounts/registerBusiness.html', context)

def activate(request, uidb64, token ):
    #activate user email from token vertifcation(setting =True)
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = User._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your account has been sucessfully verifed and is now active! Thank you for your interest')
        return redirect ('myAccount')
    else:
        messages .error(request, 'invalid link, please try again')
        return redirect ('myAccount')
    


# manage form details for login, logour and loop incase of error or mistype of passowrd

#manages the pages based on the user roles and permissions for logging in
def user_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, 'You have already logged into your account')
        return redirect('dashboard')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)  # Rename the function call to auth_login
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully logged in.')
            return redirect('myAccount')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid login details. Please check and try again.')
            return redirect('login')

    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
# manage user accounts, reset password, login and register
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    messages.info(request, 'You have logged out succesfully')
    return redirect('login')

@login_required(login_url='login')
def myAccount(request):
    user = request.user
    redirectUrl = detectUser(user)
    return redirect(redirectUrl)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@user_passes_test(check_role_buss)
def bussDash(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/bussDash.html')

@login_required(login_url='login')
@user_passes_test(check_role_customer)
def custDash(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/custDash.html')

def forgot_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(email__exact=email)    

            #send reset password email, used verfication email function instead to make it more efficient
            mail_subject = 'Reset Password Link'
            email_template = 'accounts/emails/reset_password_email.html'
            send_verification_email(request, user, mail_subject, email_template)

            messages.success(request, 'You password reset link has been sent to the added email address')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Account does not exist. Please recheck your email address')
            return redirect('forgot_password')

    return render(request, 'accounts/forgot_password.html')

def reset_password_validate(request, uidb64, token):
    User = get_user_model()
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        request.session['uid'] = uid
        messages.info(request, 'Please reset your password')
        return redirect('reset_password')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid reset password link.')
        return redirect('myAccount')

def reset_password(request, uidb64, token):
    User = get_user_model()
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            password = request.POST['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your password has been reset successfully. Please log in with your new password.')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            context = {
                'uidb64': uidb64,
                'token': token,
            }
            return render(request, 'accounts/reset_password.html', context)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid reset password link.')
        return redirect('myAccount')


def reset_password(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/emails/reset_password_email.html')
```

account_verf_email.html

```
{% autoescape off%}
<!-- security feature to prevent cross scripting -->

Hi {{user.first_name}}, 

Please verify your email address by clicking on the below link. 
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}


{% endautoescape %}
```

I have doubled checked the routing and the uid is been called Im not sure why its not reseting the passowrd link or redirecting to the reset_password URL. I adapted the answer from this here: [Django : No Reverse Match on password reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526042/django-no-reverse-match-on-password-reset)  and here: [NoReverseMatch on password_Reset_confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143393/noreversematch-on-password-reset-confirm)

I really appreciate your help thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two views called reset_password in your views.py

Your reset_password_activate view calls this one:

```
return redirect('reset_password')
```

which your URLs.py decodes as this route (Note it is being referred to as views.reset_password)

```
path('reset_password/', views.reset_password, name='reset_password'),
```

the first reset_password view in views.py is this one

```
def reset_password(request, uidb64, token):
```

(you may have meant this one at the bottom)

```
def reset_password(request):
```

But your path isn't describing any arguments, so uidb64 is unexpected, as per the error.

The easisest way to fix is simply to rename one of the two views and make sure each is pointing/being pointed at correctly.

Comment: Awh okay I see! Thanks so much SamSparx this was very helpful!